# PHP fetch pdo with hyphen in column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

So I'm writing a php project and I got stuck on hyphens in column names of a table in a database.
I have the following code:

```
 $results = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     foreach ($results as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#<?= $row->factuur-status ?>"><?= $row->factuur-status ?></a></td>
        <td><?= $row->verkoop-orderid ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Now obviously because of the hyphens in the column names this doesn't work.
How can one fix this?

Comment: use ` to escape the hyphen column names

Comment: I can't use those (``) in the code I have written. I already tried that...

Answer (score 1):

I found it, if someone's interested:

```
<?= $row->{'factuur-status'} ?>
```